# Sell function but with accepting only another erc20 token, not eth

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, crowdsale, presale

I want to sell my token (PRO TOKEN) to users in my presale, but I dont want people to send ETH or any other crypto to buy from my smart contract. I want people to buy my PRO TOKEN by sending CRAPPYTOKEN to my smart contract and they will automatically receive PRO TOKENS.

Here is what I have, but it only accepts ETH. I just manually send PRO TOKENS to the contract to sell, thats not a problem for me.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
library SafeMath{
function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
c = a + b;
require(c >= a);
}
function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
require(b <= a);
c = a - b;
}
function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
c = a * b;
require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
}
function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
require(b > 0);
c = a / b;
}
}
contract ERC20Interface {
function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}
contract Owned {
address public owner;
constructor() public {
owner = msg.sender;
}
modifier onlyOwner {
require(msg.sender == owner);
_;
}
}
contract Presale is Owned{
using SafeMath for uint256;
ERC20Interface public token;
uint256 public rate = 1; // 1 tokens per ETH
event TokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, uint256 value, uint256 amount);
constructor() public {
token = ERC20Interface(0x2f4Ae24fDC6E18945eC2Ba1756B421B8157Ec34A); // Your SmartContract address
}
function () external payable {
buyTokens();
}
function buyTokens() payable public {
require(msg.sender != 0x0);
uint256 amount = msg.value;
uint256 tokens = getTokenAmount(amount);
deliverTokens(msg.sender, tokens);
emit TokenPurchase(msg.sender, amount, tokens);
}
function deliverTokens(address beneficiary,uint256 tokenAmount) internal{
require(tokenAmount > 0, "Can't buy zero or negative");
require(tokenAmount <= token.balanceOf(address(this)), "Can't buy more than allocated");
require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) > 0, "");
token.transfer(beneficiary, tokenAmount);
}
function getTokenAmount(uint256 amount) public view returns (uint256){
return rate.mul(amount);
}
function tokensHere() public view returns(uint256) {
return token.balanceOf(address(this));
}
function WithdrawBNB() onlyOwner() public {
require(address(this).balance > 0, "Can't withdraw negative or zero");
(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
}
```

This code works if I want to sell my PRO TOKEN an receiving ETH, so the question is, how to disable receive ETH and only accept CRAPPYTOKEN ?

Both tokens are worthless and not listed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do this too.
But have no time to test anything for now.

You can make a test for both us...

Try to send your token to the fallback function and see what is the result.

I think you may check the incomming token ... don't now.